# Python inspect: Get arguments of specific decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a script that given a function returns the arguments of a specific decorator.

Imagine the following function:

```py
@decorator_a
@decorator_b(41,42,43)
@decorator_c(45)
def foo(self):
    return 'bar'
```

I need a function that given `foo` returns the arguments of `decorator_b` - something like `[41,42,43]`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of trying out different stuff I figured out a feasible solution:

```
inspect.getclosurevars(foo.__wrapped__).nonlocals
```

If you know the argument names of the decorator you try to inspect you can check for existence in the `nonlocals` dict. If it's not there, check one `__wrapped__` layer higher and so on.